# Giving a grouped UITableView "First Crack" at touches when using a section header view containing a control

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using a standard grouped style UITableView that returns a custom header view for one of it's sections (using the tableView's delegate method viewForHeaderInSection:). The view that is returned for the section header contains a control. It displays an image and is a control so it can tapped to let the user change the image. My desired UI is similar to the photo for a contact in the Apple Contacts app (a floating imageView-like control in a grouped style table).

The problem I'd like to solve is that touches on the tableView section header go straight to the control. I'd like the table to get a chance to determine if the touch is actually the beginning of a scroll gesture. If not, then the table can pass the event to the section header view for processing.

This is how all the rows in the table behave since I have "delaysContentTouches" for the table on. I suspect the problem is because the section header view is not in the table's view hierarchy. So everything is probably working per spec. just not the way I want.

**I want the section header view to behave regarding touches just like rows do (table gets first chance to process).**

BTW I am not placing this control in a table row (which would solve the problem) because I want the rounded rect grouped style for all table rows, but not for this one UI element. This control is in the center of my table (header for section 1) which is why I want drags on it to scroll the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so apparently this is simulator issue only. On a device my tableView gets the first chance at the event. So I guess I need to listen to the Apple mantra of "always test on an actual device" before posting to StackOverflow. Sorry friends... may my error be helpful to others who, like me, probably spend too much time in the simulator.